# Mongoose - updating object inside an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Schema that looks like this:

```
const RefSchema = {
  active: Boolean,
  items: [{}],
};
const TopLevelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  refs: [RefSchema],
  ...
}, { timestamps: true });
```

I'm making an API call to update this one of the `refs` using its `id` (below its `rid`) and some data that's inside the API call:

```
async function updateRef(id, rid, data) {
  // First get the TopLevelSchema by the ID - this is OK
  const instance = await this.findById(id).exec();
  // Prepare the data:
  const $set = _.mapKeys(data, (v, k) => `refs.$.${k}`);
  // Update the data
  await instance.update(
    { 'refs.id': rid },
    { $set },
  );
```

What's happening is that the data (and e.g. I'm passing `{ active: true }`) is not updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to first get the `TopLevelSchema` etc. You can update the child like this:

```
async function updateRef(rid, data) {
   let $set = _.mapKeys(data, (v, k) => `refs.$.${k}`)
   await TopLevelSchema.updateOne(
     { 'refs._id' : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(rid) },
     { $set })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I did. It even worked without wrapping the `rid` with the `ObjectId` function. Now I'm just wondering if there is a way to do it from the `document` level

Answer (score 0):

are you using custom ids? because you should do `{ '_id': rid }` instead   `{ 'refs.id': rid }`

Comment: No custom ids in this case